# Checking current location with location's which are stored in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have to generate Notification Alert whenever my current location get match with the location stored in the Database.
So I used google places API for user type the location and then it get stored in the database so i have to write one service for getting current location from LocationListener and then how can I check location stored in database?

Can any one suggest me that how to check ?
with the help of location text with the current text **or** getting latitude and longitude ?

Comment: What you have tried till now? What is exact problem in that.

Comment: till now getting current location and location typed in autocompletetextview stored in database but I am confuse which is the beneficial way to check current location with the stored location with lat longs or direct text checking?

Comment: have you fired sql query for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches that could be used here but in each of those the comparison should be depending on `latitude and longitude` (at least that what I use in similar situations).

For sure you can't compare the exact value of `latitude and longitude` with another stored `latitude and longitude`; it is logically wrong and almost impossible to happen.

***a better approach would be:***

**1-create a virtual circle around the stored location `(lat,lng)`.**

[image]

here the circle is just for demonstration purposes what you need in your code is:

`Location.distanceBetween()` method.

lets say you need to compare within 500 meters the code would look like this:

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(storedLatitude, storedLongitude, currentLatitude, currentLongitude, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];
boolean within500m = distanceInMeters < 500;
```

2-get returned boolean

`if(true) -> //result(your code when stored location = current)`

`if(false) ->// result(your code when stored location != current)`.

Comment: Yes I think this is best way, can u refer me any demo about this example, i am getting quite confuse how to do it?

Comment: it is actually pretty simple if you are using Google Maps API you just need to write the above code; i don't really know when you need to call this method but lets say you need to call it after the user perform a click; then into onClickListener implement the above code and then depending on the returned value of within500m perform your action

Comment: Hello Ahmad Alsanie!! how can i get those lat and longs which are match to distanceBetween() method.